# Can I make hotremove/add on raid5 with mdadm?

Tags: raid, mdadm, ssd

I created and assembled software RAID5 array (mdadm), 15 SSD disks.
If I physically remove several disks and add them back, RAID doesn't assembles back. Disks stays in "spare" mode. Even after reassembling by commands.

But if I manually fail a drives: *mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sd[xyz]* and then after *mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sd[xyz]* remove physically and add disks back, with command *mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sd[xyz]* RAID works fine!

Can anybody guess me, if there is a hot swap\remove\add in soft-raid **mdadm** or not?
Should I always use commands **before** removing disks? No automation?

Comment: Please don't use R5, most storage professionals have considered it wildly dangerous for over a decade and we can't believe it's still an option on disk controllers and in OS's - we deal with people all the time who come here asking for help getting their data back from a broken R5. Please only use R1/10, R6/60 or ZRAID if you like that kind of thing - R5 has been 'dead' for a long time.

Comment: RAID 5 can only tolerate the loss of a single drive.  If you lose two drives, the array is inoperative until you can bring the second failed drive back. This is a limitation of RAID 5 generally, not something specific to Linux.